# looking for UX suggestions

Tags: design-ethics

just after some opinions on some UI. The UI is based on an existing system that is a windows desktop application converted to the web and it matches very close. The desktop version runs a scrollbox with frames in it. The new one uses divs in a table, the only problem is that I honestly dont like the look of it, its big and doesnt feel right. So looking for suggestions, its a little untidy, its incomplete but you get the idea.[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: This type of question isn't suitable for this site. If the only problem is that you don't like the look of it, it should be posted on a site where you can ask for graphic design suggestions.

Comment: Not really this is a UX forum is it not?

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of errors in there. To begin with, the labels should be left aligned not centered, the second column of inputs is way to close to the left one, the third column has no text for those checkboxes etc.

Try following best practices for forms. There is a plethora of articles on this.
https://uxdesign.cc/the-ux-behind-designing-better-forms-d6ebe7a817d2

Comment: lol yes the design is very rough and I will have a look at those links thank you

Answer (score 2):

1. I would consider organising the fields in groups so it looks more organised and pleasing. It will also help remove some uncertainty from users as groups of similar information will give a more clear meaning to some of the elements.
2. This could also help in you adding a discreet progress bar to motivate users adding information. Examples: https://dribbble.com/shots/5756582-Upart-Form-Process-Animation & https://dribbble.com/shots/3822992-Registration-Form
3. Spacing is not done well and needs to be improved for sure. Within that text alignment as well. There are some typos (e.g. All days start with a capital letter but Saturday and Sunday). I am not sure what P/H and some of your users might not know either - everything should be very clear unless your users are familiar with it.
4. Consider checking how this works just by using a keyboard and not a mouse if that matches with the type of users you have.
5. There are elements that I can't understand where they belong (e.g. Active, Modified, From Template). Maybe categories or better labelling would be helpful there.
6. It seems like it is a demanding interface so consider creating shortcuts for your users. E.G. When they choose days maybe include "All weekdays" if that makes sense, or instead of having them start from a blank space create "templates" or "recipes" (this might be completely irrelevant and dangerous if it doesn't match you user needs).

Comment: Thanks ill check out the suggestions and go from there, I came up with a different layout last night I need to trial as well, thank you.

Comment: Feel free to send it for feedback :)